# all matches per id on one line to one match per id per line

Tags: unix, sed

I have a tab delimited text file like so:

```
Gene1 ID:454,ID:575,ID:44449
Gene2 ID:4344,ID:5626,ID:4
Gene3 ID:244
```

And Id like to get htis into long form, e.g.

```
Gene1 ID:454
Gene1 ID:575
Gene1 ID:44449
Gene2 ID:4344
Gene2 ID:5626
Gene2 ID:4
Gene3 ID:244
```

I thought I could do this with sed, going line by line, replacing each comma with the first string up to space (GeneX) plus the element before the comma andthen adding a new line, but wasn't making much progress. And in some cases there is only one match (no comma) to complicate the parsing.

Is sed even the right way to go with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -ane '
           @ids = split /,/, $F[1];
           print "$F[0]\t$_\n" for @ids;
          ' < input.txt > output.txt
```

- `-n` reads the file line by line
- `-a` splits each line on whitespace to the `@F` array
- `split` creates an array from a string - here, it splits the second (`$F[1]`) field on commas

Answer (score 0):

Using awk.

```
awk -F , '{
    # Pull off the Gene## string.
    g=substr($1, 1, index($1, " "))
    # Set the output field separator to a newline followed by the gene string.
    OFS="\n"g
    # Force awk to recombine the current line with the new value of OFS.
    # This *should*, canonically, work as $0=$0 I believe but it doesn't
    # work when I do that here and I don't know why.
    $1=$1
    print
}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^((\S+\s)[^,]*),/\1\n\2/;P;D' file
```

This replaces the first `,` by the preceeding tokens followed by a newline and then the first token and its following whitespace. The first line is then printed and discarded and the procedure repeated until no further `,`'s are substituted.